# dispatch a running Python application from console

Tags: python, console

I want to run my `Python` application without associating it to the console (the `Python` process will be active and the console free for use )

Is there any way to do this ?

EDIT: I'm using `Ubuntu 12.10` on my machine and `Debian 6` on my server

Comment: Do you have any particular operating system in mind?

Comment: @icktoofay sorry I forgot to mention it! I've made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for an arbitrary command line application run from the console by using `disown` like so:

```
$ { python the_app.py & } && disown
```

If you don't want to see the output of your application (if any) then redirect output to `/dev/null` like so

```
$ { python the_app.py >/dev/null 2>&1 & } && disown
```

If you want to write the output to a file instead of sending your output into the black hole that is `/dev/null` just replace `/dev/null` with a file name.

```
$ { python the_app.py >not_a_black_hole.txt 2>&1 & } && disown
```

Comment: that's what i'm looking for, thanks. is there any way to see the output of the process again when using your second command ?

Comment: See my answer above. You can write to a file and then inspect that later. I'm not sure if that's what you meant though. What exactly do you mean "see it again"? Do you mean you want to have a switch that allows you to see the output/hide it?

Comment: what I want to do exactly is to let the python script run in my server (the script echoes the state of the operation), and to be able to check the logging stat (like I'm not using disown)

Comment: In that case you can do `tail -f not_a_black_hole.txt` which will auto update `tail` as new output is written (interrupt it with Ctrl-C). You can also do `less +F --follow-name not_a_black_hole.txt`.

Comment: I think there is other solutions using `screen`, but this seems to work! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to create a daemon. Use this: [daemonize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize)